# How to add decimal point a automatic rounded division PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, decimal, rounding, division

I have a code who likes like this:

```
SELECT 
a,
b,
c,
a/b/c AS d
FROM data
```

with results like this:

```
a   | b  | c   | d
----|----|-----|----
248  4     1     62
----|----|-----|----
 99   2     1    49   
----|----|-----|----
2077   1   675   3
```

instead of give 49.50 & 3.07 the division automatically rounds my results and i need numbers with 2 decimal points

I've tried it with the round() argument

```
ROUND(a/b/c,2) as d
```

but that doesn't work

I've trying with NUMERIC & DECIMAL but the console gives syntax errors
(f.e syntax error at or near "AS" )

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast either of  the values a,b or c.

try the following

```
 SELECT  
 a,
 b,
 c,
 a::float/b/c AS d
 FROM data
```